# JavaScript: native forEach vs native forEach

Tags: javascript, performance, foreach

I noticed that native forEach sometimes occurs to be too slowly even for small arrays. Look at this example:

```
var a = [], b = []; 
a[1234567] = 'foo'; 
b[10] = 'bar'; 

a.forEach(function(arg1, arg2) { console.log(arg1, arg2); }); //1
//vs 
b.forEach(function(arg1, arg2) { console.log(arg1, arg2); }); //2
```

In my Chromium (25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.04) execution times of line 1 and line 2 are different order of magnitude. I know than lenght of **a** is equal to 1234568, and for **b** it is equal just to 10. But does native forEach implementation is such naive? Both **a** and **b** are consist of only one element. How this behavior could be explained?

Comment: If a had only one element, it's length would be 1. Doesn't `b[10] =` automatically create a value for `b[9]`, `b[8]`, etc?

Comment: Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods), the iteration methods sample an array's length before they start. Thus, forEach will iterate over every possible index for a, even if there is only one element defined in that array.

Comment: @jpaugh: it doesn't, it just becomes a sparse array then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because `a`'s length is actually 1234568, so you have to loop over 1234568 elements because how else can you be sure the elements aren't there?

```
var a = []
a[1234567] = 'foo'
console.log(a.length) // 1234568
```

So, it is looping over 1234566 of nothing and 1 `'foo'`, vs array `b` which is only looping over 9 "nothing"s and a `'bar'`.

When `foreach` tries to read `a[0]`, it realizes it's not there, because `a` has nothing at index `0`. Therefore, `foreach` thinks like this:

```
I'm going to see what a[0] is!
Oh no! It's not there!
I'm going to see what a[1] is!
Oh no! It's not there!
I'm going to see what a[2] is!
Oh no! It's not there!
...
I'm going to see what a[1234567] is!
Yaaaaay! I found it! Now I'll print it!
```

That's why it takes so much longer.

Comment: Wrong, as you can see with `for…in` or `hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: @PointedEars Please elaborate? What part of the answer is wrong?

Comment: The array does not contain `undefined` elements. Reading the property only yields `undefined`, as with any other property that does not exist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31452/discussion-between-ostrovski-and-doorknob)

Answer (score 5):

`forEach` iterates over the full length of the array, skipping non-existent elements on the way. Although `a` and `b` only contain one element, their `length` is big so you're giving `forEach` a hard time iterating.

After all, it's in the specification! An excerpt of [ES5 15.4.4.18 Array.prototype.forEach](http://es5.github.io/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.18):

> 6) Let k be 0.
>
> 7) Repeat, while k < len

To demonstrate this, let's see how Firefox's SpiderMonkey implements these steps:

```
/* Steps 6-7. */
/* Steps a (implicit), and d. */
for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
    /* Step b */
    if (k in O) {
        /* Step c. */
        callFunction(callbackfn, T, O[k], k, O);
    }
}
```

You can clearly see the loop of `k` from `0` to `len` which lies at the base of your performance troubles. For almost all `k`, `k in O` yields `false` but you still feel the impact of a million iterations and a million `k in O` tests.

For reference, here are the links to the [SpiderMonkey](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/blob/03ea22b3c6e6b3c305138b44a784663578bb6be1/js/src/builtin/Array.js#L185) and  [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/8ae7cef19427362d2fb1c1fa4951050df6fe2e61/src/array.js#L1188) implementations at the time of writing.

Comment: @PointedEars No, you're talking nonsense. `for(var i in a)` is *NOT* equivalent to `a.forEach`!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I have not claimed that it would. Wrong is your assertion that the array contains as many elements. It does not. The value of the `length` property does not yield the number of elements in an array, only the highest index + 1.

Comment: @PointedEars, `length` actually yields the number of elements in an array, as far as the iterating methods are concerned, which is indeed also the highest index + 1. This first element is at index 0. Hence, there are `length` elements in the array. Whether some of these elements are undefined or not is another matter. (Arrays are not associative arrays.)

Comment: @Bruno No, read the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4). There are no `undefined` elements. There is *no* element at the index, hence no such property, and using the name of a property that does not exist yields `undefined`.

Comment: @PointedEars, yes, but the iterating methods go over these elements, whether they are defined or not. (See Dancrumb's answer.)

Comment: @PointedEars, if you read further down in [the link you sent](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) (forEach section), it does start at "*Let k be 0*" and end at "*len*" (where *len* is the result of getting the `length` property).

Comment: @PointedEars, and you've also added your own answer which contradicts every other (negative) comment of yours you've made on other answers (answers you may have downvoted too)... A bit cheeky ;-)

Comment: @Bruno Nonsense! That the element with that index does not exist is the root cause for the method call to take long *and* the function not being called regardless.

Answer (score 4):

> But [is] the native `forEach` implementation [so] naive? Both **a** and **b** [consist] of only one element. How [could] this behavior […] be explained?

It is specified so in the [ECMAScript Language Specification, 5.1 Edition, §15.4.4.18](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18):

> When the **`forEach`** method is called with one or two arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *O* be the result of calling [`ToObject`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9) passing the **this** value as the argument.
> 2. Let *lenValue* be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of *O* with the argument `"length"`.
> 3. Let *len* be [`ToUint32`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6)`(`*lenValue*`)`.
> 4. If [`IsCallable`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.11)`(`*callbackfn*`)` is **false**, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 5. If *thisArg* was supplied, let *T* be *thisArg*; else let *T* be **undefined**.
> 6. Let *k* be 0.
> 7. Repeat, while *k* < *len*
>
>    > a. Let *Pk* be [`ToString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)`(`*k*`)`.
>    >
>    > b. Let *kPresent* be the result of calling the `[[HasProperty]]` internal method of *O* with argument *Pk*.
>    >
>    > c. If *kPresent* is **true**, then
>    >
>    > > i. Let *kValue* be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of *O* with argument *Pk*.
>    > >
>    > > ii. Call the `[[Call]]` internal method of *callbackfn* with *T* as the **this** value and argument list containing *kValue*, *k*, and *O*.
>    >
>    > d. Increase *k* by 1.
> 8. Return **undefined**.

Steps 6 and 7 require a conforming implementation to iterate through *all* indexes, from the first index `0` to the last one, `a.length - 1`, *regardless* whether there is an array element with that index.  Which explains why the `forEach` method call takes so long if the last index is a large number.

However, because in step 7b (the implementation of) the `[[HasProperty]]` internal method must return **false** for indexes for which there is no array element, the callback *callbackfn* is *not* called for those indexes.  Which explains why there is only one `console.log` call when executing the `forEach` method call.